# create postgres table within schema, from csv file, using sqlalchemy, not working, strange error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

** Update:

Per Adrian Klaver's suggestion, I have got the following:

```
porter_test2=# show search_path;

   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

So I then typed
`set search_path to dbo,public;` in psql, and now `\d` shows the tables that I was looking for!

It does seem as though some things are working.  However, now I need to figure out how to determine/set all column types in the call to `.to_sql(...)`, because I am getting errors referencing memory issues.  I'm looking at posts related to that, but any hints are appreciated.

---

---

I'm trying to write a script that automates the creation of tables from `.csv` files.  So far, I've pieced it together using things I've taken from other posts here.  I'm very new to sql, postgresql, and pandas, so I'm probably doing this pretty inefficiently.

NOTE:  Even though I emphasize a weird error, the biggest issue is that the tables are not being created at all!

First, I create the database and schema in psql, like so (I've already created the user "porter_test2"):

```
postgres=# create database porter_test2;
postgres=# grant all privileges on database porter_test2 to porter_test2;
postgres=# \c porter_test2;
porter_test2=# create schema dbo;
porter_test2=# grant all on schema dbo to porter_test2;
```

Now, when I type `\dn`, I see:

```
porter_test2=# \dn
      List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner
--------+-------------------
 dbo    | postgres
 public | pg_database_owner
(2 rows)
```

So, it seems like I successfully created the `dbo` schema (the default schema for me is `public`).  Now, I'd like to add tables to the database, within the schema I created.  Here's my attempt at that:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql://porter_test2:[my_password]@localhost:5432/porter_test2')

file_list = ["table1.csv"]

for file in file_list:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    table_name = file[:-4]
    df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, schema = 'dbo')
```

Running this script once produces no errors or output.  But when I type `\d` in psql, I see:

```
porter_test2=# \d
Did not find any relations.
```

So something is obviously wrong with what I'm doing.  FURTHERMORE, if I run the python script again, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blaug\OneDrive\Documents\work\scott_porter_project\Truvy-Customer-Lead-Scoring-main\Truvy-Customer-Lead-Scoring-main\ziplingo-score-leads\zz_prep_stuff\z_scripts\create_tables_from_files\zz_tables_from_csv_1.py", line 28, in <module>
    df.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, schema = 'dbo')
  File "C:\Users\blaug\miniconda3\envs\mlm\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2987, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\blaug\miniconda3\envs\mlm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 695, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\blaug\miniconda3\envs\mlm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1728, in to_sql
    table = self.prep_table(
  File "C:\Users\blaug\miniconda3\envs\mlm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1631, in prep_table
    table.create()
  File "C:\Users\blaug\miniconda3\envs\mlm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 829, in create
    raise ValueError(f"Table '{self.name}' already exists.")
ValueError: Table 'table1' already exists.
```

Based on this error, I naturally type `\d` in psql, but this again yields `Did not find any relations.`

I tried adding `if exists='replace'` in my `df.to_sql(...)` call, and this does prevent the error shown above, instead yielding no output or errors.  But, like before, no relations are seen when I type `\d` in psql.

I'm pretty confused!  I need to make these tables, and it's not working!  I suspect that there are problems at multiple levels with my approach here.  I basically want to write a python script that takes a list of `.csv` files and creates tables from them (with the same names as the files) within a specified postgres database AND schema.  I don't really understand schemas very well, but later I need to be able to access these tables with querys like `... FROM dbo.table1 ...`, where `dbo` is the schema in which I created the table.

Comment: maybe it is only something that was left from prior tests, have you looked with pgpadmin too

Comment: Betting it is [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue. In `psql` try `\d dbo.*`. Also do `show search_path;` and add result as update to question.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, I added the results as an update.  And I modified the search path, and now ```\d``` shows my tables!  Thank you!  Now, to figure out how to find the column types ahead of time so the entire tables don't need to be read (which kills execution for the bigger csv files)...

Comment: 1) I would say they don't show up in pgAdmin4 because you are probably looking in wrong database. Check you connection settings to verify you are connecting to same Postgres server in all cases. 2) Why do you need to know the column types? CSV data is all text, so as long as the data values  are suitably formatted the type does not matter.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, I just restarted pgAdmin4 and they show up now.  As for the columns, I read that I "need" to know them because creating the tables as I am, without providing types ahead of time, prompts python to load the entire file before "deciding" what the column type is.  I have 32gb of memory and for the bigger files it seems to nearly use all of that.  This logic comes from another stack overflow post, to which i've lost the link.  I guess providing column types allows rows to be read/written one at a time?

Comment: Ditch Panda and especially `to_sql`, they are  resources hogs for this sort of thing. Just use `psycopg2` directly, in particular its [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#copy) support.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, that sounds great.  I'm getting somewhere, but... can you suggest anything about copying to NEW tables (i'm getting a 'relation doesn't exist' error)?  keeping in mind that my original problem included generating the new table from the csv file, not knowing ahead of time column names or data types.

Comment: Missed the part about creating new tables. You might use the `nrows` argument to [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to create the table with a subset of the CSV and then use `to_sql()` with `append` to get the rest of the rows in .